# React component only changes state on second onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I have these two *simplified* React components, where the `Times` component is a child of the `Create` component (see below for code samples). The expected behavior is that initially, the `Times` component is not shown, but when the user clicks on the link with `onClick`, the `Times` component appears.

The components work as expected for the most part, but strangely, after clicking on the `onClick` link for the first time, the `Times` component does not appear and the `Create` component does not change state at all as is shown in the console. However, when clicking on the link a second time, the `Create` component does change state and rerenders, and the `Times` component is seen.

**Create.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Times from './Times.jsx';

export default React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {times: false};
  },

  _change: function () {
    this.replaceState({times: true});
    console.log(this.state.times);
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div id="create">
        <div id="outerbox">
          <a onClick={this._change}>Times</a>
          <Times shouldShow={this.state.times}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

**Times.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    shouldShow: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  },

  getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {shouldShow: false};
  },

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {el: 'times'};
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    if (this.props.shouldShow === false) {
      this.setState({display: 'none'});
    } else {
      this.setState({display: 'block'});
    }
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps: function() {
    if (this.props.shouldShow === false) {
      this.setState({display: 'none'});
    } else {
      this.setState({display: 'block'});
    }
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div id={this.state.el} style={{"display": this.state.display}}>
        <h1>Times</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

**Output of console.log**

```
false
true
```

**Why is the state of the `Create` component not being registered on the first click?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is here.

```
 componentWillReceiveProps: function() {
    if (this.props.shouldShow === false) {
      this.setState({display: 'none'});
    } else {
      this.setState({display: 'block'});
    }
  }
```

Which should be,

```
 componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps) {
    if (newProps.shouldShow === false) {
      this.setState({display: 'none'});
    } else {
      this.setState({display: 'block'});
    }
  }
```

ComponentWillRecieveProps is a member function of the component class that gets called just before props are "applied". Which means that `this.props` are old Props. You should use `newProps` which is served to the function as an argument.

http://codepen.io/bhargav175/pen/gaJmKz

---

Also, I get the feeling that you are using a little more state than you need. You dont need the display as a state variable at all. Times is an inner component, so it makes sense to use props as much as possible and make them stateless.

There is a common misconception around that "props change don't affect the render, so lets use state". Props change results in rerender too, so always use props unless there is a strong reason and you really need to make an inner component intelligent. Using props in inner components, makes them dumb and easier to use.

http://codepen.io/bhargav175/pen/WQBpzP

```
   var Times = React.createClass({

  propTypes: {
    shouldShow: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired
  },

  getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {shouldShow: false};
  },

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {el: 'times'};
  },



  render: function () {
    let display = this.props.shouldShow ? "block" : "none";
    return (
      <div id={this.state.el} style={{"display": display}}>
        <h1>Times</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```